# Mongoid Find Parent Object by Child Object ID

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a residence object that contains users.  However, in my application there is an edge case where the application will know the user but not the residence they are a member of.  Is there a way to get the parent residence object based on a unique ID of a user?

```
class User 
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :email, type: String
    field :firstName, type: String
    field :lastName, type: String
end

class Residence
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name, type: String
    field :updateTime, type: DateTime

    embeds_many :groceryLists
    embeds_many :events
    embeds_many :messages
    embeds_many :users
end
```

Something along the lines of:

```
user_id = foo
Residence.is_any(users._id: user_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think class User should also have

```
embedded_in :Residence
```

Then just do

```
Residence.where('users._id'=> user_id).first
```